# loading CKEditor5 components with React.lazy

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, lazy-loading, ckeditor5

In my project I want to use CKEditor5. Problem is, this version is not compatible with IE11 so my goal is to lazy load CKEditor5 components and when IE11 is detected, I dont want to simply load those components.

When component is imported like this `import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";` it just importing class, however with `React.lazy` import component is wrapped with `React.LazyExoticComponent`.

I need to create instance of `GFMDataProcessor` according to documentation https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/markdown.html

But with dynamic import I am not able to do that, since this line of code throws an error and I dont know what argument should I pass, since `GFMDataProcessor` is `React.LazyExoticComponent` and not `GFMDataProcessor` class.

```
//Expected 1 arguments, but got 0  
const markdownPlugin = (editor) => { editor.data.processor = new GFMDataProcessor() }
```

Other problem is with my configuration for CKEditor, it has to be lazy loaded also and here is the same problem as above, `ClassicEditor` is again `React.LazyExoticComponent` instead of class and I have to pass to `editor` property imported component, not the wrapped one with `React.LazyExoticComponent`. Is there some way how I can extract dynamically imported component from wrapped one or any other way how can this be solved?

```
const ckeditorProps = {
        data: data,
        editor: ClassicEditor,
        onChange: (event, editor) => {
            const data2 = editor.getData();
            if (data2 !== data) {
                this.onChange(data2, this.state.selectedCultureCode, true);
            }
        },
        config: editorConfiguration
    }
```

Here are my dynamic imports

```
const CKEditor = React.lazy(() => import("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react"));
const ClassicEditor = React.lazy(() => import("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic"));
const GFMDataProcessor = React.lazy(() => import("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm/src/gfmdataprocessor"));
```

Usage in DOM structure

```
<React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <CKEditor {...ckeditorProps} />
</React.Suspense>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you wrap anything you want to be fetched asynchronously into the `React.lazy` components. You should just fetch them normally when they're needed. Maybe something like the following will work for you:

```
let ClassicEditor, GFMDataProcessor;

const LazyCKEditor = React.lazy(() => {
    return Promise.all([
        import("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic"),
        import("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react"),
        import("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm/src/gfmdataprocessor")
    ]).then(([ _ClassicEditor, _CKEditor, _GFMDataProcessor ]) => {
        ClassicEditor = _ClassicEditor;
        GFMDataProcessor = _GFMDataProcessor;

        return _CKEditor;
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work